# Will not boot to prompt after do-release-upgrade; gdm not running xserver

Tags: server, upgrade

Oneiric will not boot to prompt after `do-release-upgrade`; gdm not running xserver but it will boot a previous kernel version. Where are the log files? The hdd has been running something for 3 hours.

Answer (score 1):

3.0 dmesg is nearly identical to previous versions; however `sudo apt-get remove`  will return "previous installation interupted please run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`" this will fix the problem.